# Multiply audio signals for robot voice C#

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, wav

I'm trying to get the wave output of .NET SpeechSynthesizer to make the voice sound like robot-ish.

After some research, I have found that ring modulation might be a good option to obtain the effect I want. I have seen that the formula is basically `Result(t) = Voice(t) * SineWave(t)`.

Although, I have no idea of how I could apply this effect from a Wave Stream, is there any library out there to :

- Generate a sine wave and process it into a Wave Stream
- Multiply both Streams in order to get the result

If not, do you know any other option ? Maybe I could multiply each sample in the Voice Wave Stream by each sample in the sine wave ?

I'm using C# /.net framework.

Thank you !

**Edit :** Okay, so after a few hours of failed attempts, I've finally came up with what seems to be the good result. The only problem is that there's a lot of crackling on the output, and the only fix I've found is to apply a low pass filter.

Here's what I've got so far (quick, dirty and uncommented code, but should be self explanatory):

```
class Mixer
{
    public static Stream RingModulation(Stream voiceStream, TimeSpan duration, SpeechAudioFormatInfo format)
    {
        var sineWave = SineOscillator.GenerateWave(duration, 80, 1, format);
        var numSamples = Convert.ToInt32(duration.TotalSeconds * format.SamplesPerSecond);
        var dataStream = new MemoryStream();

        sineWave.Position = 0;
        voiceStream.Position = 0;

        var buf1 = new byte[2];
        var buf2 = new byte[2];
        for (var i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
        {
            voiceStream.Read(buf1, 0, 2);
            sineWave.Read(buf2, 0, 2);

            var data = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt16(BitConverter.ToInt16(buf1, 0) * BitConverter.ToInt16(buf2, 0)));
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        return dataStream;
    }
}

class SineOscillator
{
    public static Stream GenerateWave(TimeSpan duration, double frequency, int amplitude, SpeechAudioFormatInfo format)
    {
        var numSamples = Convert.ToInt32(duration.TotalSeconds * format.SamplesPerSecond);
        var dataStream = new MemoryStream();
        var angle = (Math.PI * 2 * frequency) / (format.SamplesPerSecond * format.ChannelCount);

        for (var i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
        {
            var data = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt16(amplitude * Math.Sin(angle*i)));
            // Generate a sine wave in both channels.
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        return dataStream;
    }
}
```

The low pass filter isn't applied yet, although, questions are still open in case someone has a good answer to provide and/or a better way to do it :)

Comment: are you aware that this sine(t) will = 0 in some times?

Comment: I know it will, but afaik, it's the way Ring modulation works

Answer (score 0):

I worked in audio processing for some time. Another way to have some "robot effect" was to repeat the same frequency for a few milliseconds instead of having a well smoothed curve.

Take the frequency values for an interval
Average the values
Write the average to your output buffer for the whole interval

There are different "robot effects" that do not sound the same, this will not sound like Optimus Prime but will unmistakably seem to be computer generated